# dojox DropDownSelect fixed width

Tags: javascript, dojo, fixed-width

I wonder how to set fixed width for dojox.form.DropDownSelect (version 1.3).
I tried the following:

```
<select id="selectNode"  width="100px" dojoType="dojox.form.DropDownSelect" >
   <option value="opt">Some option</option>
</select>

<select id="selectNode"  style="width: 100px" dojoType="dojox.form.DropDownSelect" >

<select id="selectNode"  class="myclass" dojoType="dojox.form.DropDownSelect" > 
.myclass = { width: 100px }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set width of DropDown Select less than width of biggest item. If you set width bigger - it would work OK. I propose to you if it possible use dijit.form.ComboBox instead of DropDownSelect . Width property for ComboBox will work in all cases. See [example](http://pastehtml.com/view/1dxhstf.html) (last item - is ComboBox)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Btw, is it possible to make ComboBox readonly? I don't need any input in the select.

Comment: ok.. in this case you should use dijit.form.FilteringSelect (it is a replacement for the native SELECT element. Like SELECT, you provide a list of acceptable value pairs consisting of text to be displayed in the INPUT box and the hidden text value to be submitted to the server on FORM submit. Unlike SELECT, the user can also freely type text and partially matched values will be shown in a pop-up menu below the INPUT text box. Unlike a ComboBox widget, unmatched user text will be flagged as an error.) documentation: http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/form/FilteringSelect